# Meu software em C# com banco de dados SQLEXPRESS LocalDB não abre em outro PC, mesmo instalando todas as dependências

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express, sql-server-localdb

1 - Meu software em C# com banco de dados SQLEXPRESS LocalDB não abre em outro PC, mesmo instalando todas as dependências.
OBS: No meu PC de Desenvolvimento funciona perfeitamente.

2 - Programas que já instalei no Cliente:
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB.
Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012.

3 - Já tentei de tudo mais não sei mais o que fazer.

Por hora, instalei o SQL Server Express 2014 como Serviço, troquei a Connection String e funcionou perfeitamente.

4 - O problema esta sendo o bendito do LocalDB.
ConnectionString que estou usando:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbMDD" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB\dbMDD.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="sdp.mdd.ui.Properties.Settings.dbMDDConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB\dbMDD.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

OBS²: Essa é a mesma ConnectionString que funciona no meu PC de Desenvolvimento!

5 - Abaixo estão os Log de Evento de Erros de quando eu abro meu Software no cliente com o Banco de Dados LocalDB:

> LOG DE ERROS 1 - .NET Runtime

```
Aplicativo: sdp.mdd.ui.exe
Versão do Framework: v4.0.30319
Descrição: O processo foi terminado devido a uma exceção sem tratamento.
Informações da Exceção: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   em System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   em NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   em NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
   em NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect, NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.IConnectionHelper)
   em NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(NHibernate.ISessionFactory)
   em NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration, NHibernate.Engine.IMapping, NHibernate.Cfg.Settings, NHibernate.Event.EventListeners)
   em NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()

Informações da Exceção: FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException
   em FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
   em sdp.mdd.infra.NHFluentlyConfiguration.Configure(Boolean)
   em sdp.mdd.infra.NHSessionFactory.get_SessionFactory()
   em sdp.mdd.infra.GerenciadorSessao.InstanciarSessao()
   em sdp.mdd.infra.UnidadeTrabalho..ctor(sdp.mdd.infra.GerenciadorSessao)
   em sdp.mdd.aplicacao.AplicacaoBase..ctor()
   em sdp.mdd.ui.ViewLogin..ctor()
   em sdp.mdd.ui.Program.Main()
```

> LOG DE ERROS 2: ApplicationError

```
    Nome do aplicativo com falha: sdp.mdd.ui.exe, versão: 2.0.0.0, carimbo de data/hora: 0x5ab14034
Nome do módulo com falha: KERNELBASE.dll, versão: 10.0.16299.309, carimbo de data/hora: 0xd3aa915c
Código de exceção: 0xe0434352
Deslocamento da falha: 0x001008f2
ID do processo com falha: 0x2cb0
Hora de início do aplicativo com falha: 0x01d3c2e6754ebbb9
Caminho do aplicativo com falha: C:\Corujasoft\sdp.mdd.ui.exe
Caminho do módulo com falha: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ID do Relatório: 0d7f4f0d-6a2a-4fd6-95bf-ac2ee422d231
Nome completo do pacote com falha: 
ID do aplicativo relativo ao pacote com falha:
```

> LOG DE ERROS 3: Windows Error Reporting

```
    Falha no bucket 1576448505465406206, tipo 5
Nome do Evento: CLR20r3
Resposta: Não disponível
ID do CAB: 0

Assinatura do problema:
P1: sdp.mdd.ui.exe
P2: 2.0.0.0
P3: 5ab14034
P4: System.Data
P5: 4.7.2633.0
P6: 5a4ed511
P7: 29fe
P8: 108
P9: J4US0MF0KIUDES4W53QMEUNNEKOCFJ5D
P10: 

Arquivos anexados:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERAF70.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB212.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB220.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB240.tmp.txt
```

Esses arquivos podem estar disponíveis em:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_sdp.mdd.ui.exe_b6991ce4e3885917e466d7d84ddefc45e7486_fb161c74_00f5bc32
```

Símbolo da análise:

```
Verificando novamente solução: 0
ID do Relatório: 0d7f4f0d-6a2a-4fd6-95bf-ac2ee422d231
Status do Relatório: 268435456
Bucket com hash: a0b828bf5e9daf1b15e0ab9036f602fe
```

Por favor me ajudem, gostaria tanto de não ter que instalar o SQLServer Express 2014 via serviço em todos meus clientes e sim apenas o SQL Server Express LocalDb que é muito mais Leve é rápido para instalar, obrigado.

Comment: Repare o caminho do seu arquivo LocalDB: `AttachDbFilename=C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB\dbMDD.mdf`. Quando você executa o programa no seu computador, o caminho *C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB* é válido, mas em outro computador ele não é mais um caminho válido, a não ser que você mapeie sua unidade *C:* para ser acessado por outro computador (por exemplo *Z:\Corujasoft\LocalDB*), ou defina permissões de compartilhamento nessa pasta e use um caminho UNC (https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/967030/what-is-unc-pathing), como *\\DENER\Corujasoft\LocalDB*.

Answer (score 1):

Repare o caminho do seu arquivo LocalDB: `AttachDbFilename=C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB\dbMDD.mdf`.

Quando você executa o programa no seu computador, o caminho `C:\Corujasoft\LocalDB` é válido, mas em outro computador ele não é mais um caminho válido, a não ser que você mapeie sua unidade `C:` para ser acessada por outro computador, como por exemplo `Z:\Corujasoft\LocalDB`, ou defina permissões de compartilhamento nessa pasta e use um caminho UNC (https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/967030/what-is-unc-pathing), como `\\DENER\Corujasoft\LocalDB`.

Answer (score 1):

Use o `Data Directory` para sinalizar que o banco localiza-se na raiz da aplicação.

Assim:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="CaminhoSQL" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
           connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
                             AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PastaSehouverUma\NomedaDB.mdf;
                             Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```